# how to access datakey value in .cs file of a listview control

Tags: asp.net

```
    protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
string id = ListView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
lblMessage.Text = "ListView Selected ID : " + id;
}
```

is there any other way to access  datakeynames values 
 in my  .aspx page datakeynames="ResourceID"

Comment: Is there anything specific you're trying to achieve by avoiding the method above?

Comment: string id = ListView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
 
i wanted  ListView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
  this  line of  code in    2 or  3 methods
 as  if  we use  methods
we cannot  get e.NewSelectedIndex

  so now i  solved my problem  by  putting into 
  thedatakey value into viewstate and again retriving if needed

Answer (score 0):

string id = ListView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
the only  we  can do is like this